# Call to undefined function wp_mail in a plugin

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, wordpress

I am trying to make a plugin which lists all users from a database with for each user a button to send an email to them. So the only way I can get with their username their email adress is to use the $POST which is given after the button is clicked. With their username I can search the db table to retreive the email. The problem here is that the page will reload and the function wp_mail is called before the pluggable.php has loaded its functions.
Here is the post:

```
if ($_POST) {
    sendEmail(current(array_keys($_POST)));
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email is sent!')</script>";
}
```

And here is the function:

```
function sendEmail($username) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT email, firstname from wp_site_users WHERE username ='" . $username ."'" , ARRAY_A);
    $mail = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * from wp_send_email WHERE id='1'", ARRAY_A);

    $to = $user['email'];
    $subject = 'Hello!';
    $message = $mail['header'] . $user['firstname'] ."\n";
    $message .= $mail['content'] . $username . "\n";
    $message .= $mail['footer'];

    $headers = 'From: '.'test@test.com'."\r\n";
    echo $to . "<br>" . $subject . "<br>" . $message . "<br>" . $headers; 
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

I've tried to add `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'sendEmail' );` at the header but that doesn't seem to work. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You need to include wp_config.php in your plugin,because this error occur when wp_config is out of reached.

Comment: You've added the javascript tag to this question so it might be ajax related, therefore: Is http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45154/need-clarification-on-how-to-correctly-call-wp-mail of any help to you?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling wp_mail before it's loaded..

Just include wp-load.php and go ahead!

```
require('../../../wp-load.php');
```

or

```
require('wp-load.php');
```

Depending how your script are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Call wp_mail after all of the necessary files are loaded:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'plugins_load' );
        
function plugins_load() {
    require MY_PLUGIN_PATH . '/includes/main.php';
        
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    wp_mail('youremail@gmail.com', 'Thank you', 'Message', $headers);
        
}
```